# Getting a row data from matching column in CSV file in Perl?

Tags: linux, awk, perl, csv

I am not able to attach the CSV file, so I have attached the images so that the content is clear. I used `awk` and `perl` one liners but that is not giving any output. Please help me know, how can I get the rows with matching column number and column text/value.

can this be written in form of a script than command.

```
$ perl -F, -lane 'print if $F[8]==WINDOWS2000-2' Compare_20180715191103.csv
```

and

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '$8 == "WINDOWS2000-2 "{ print }' Compare_20180715191103.csv
```

[image]

Comment: Well, column 8 (`H`) does not seem to contain the sting `NAB-ITSA-SOLARIS` nor `NAB-ITSA-LINUX-7` (which should have been double quoted in the Perl code btw).

Comment: You want a list of all entries where column H is equal to NAB-ITSA-LINUX-7?

Comment: Since Column S appears to contain embedded commas, is it possible earlier columns do as well? that would make a simple split based on `,` unreliable. Also, since Perl arrays are zero-indexed `$F[8]` would not be the same as Awk's `$8`

Comment: You write, "_I am not able to attach the CSV file_". That's good - I for one wouldn't want your full file. What I would want, though, is a [cut down example that illustrates the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edited with correct column 'H' value as shown in snapshot.

Comment: @Raman yes, i need the same.

Comment: Modern perl CSV-processing is entirely with `Text::CSV_XS` which is probably the best module for any language to process CSVs. And likely the fastest without doing the very same thing in C yourself. It's a shame that the module isn't a library that other languages can mooch off of.

Comment: @EvanCarroll i wrote the script with CSV_XS but its not parsing CSV file. If you allow me to message, i will show you.

Comment: @DipitSethi I only allow people to private message me that are paying me. Shy of that I ask and answer thousands of questions of this network, and do my best to give back to the community.

Comment: Post some of the lines from your csv file on which you ran your perl/awk commands and not this snapshot of the csv file opened in excel. Also tell us what you see when you run the command: `cat -vet Compare_20180715191103.csv` from the command line ?

Comment: @DipitSethi Why don't you post your script (and its output) here for all to see rather than privately sharing it with a single user?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
perl -F, -lane 'print if $F[7] eq "NAB-ITSA-LINUX-7"' URT_Compare_20180715191103.csv
```

Once you take care of the below mentioned three things, you should be fine:

1. "==" operator is for testing mathematical equality of it's operands. For string comparison, as in your case, `eq` is what you need.
2. constant strings need to be quoted, OTW they get treated as subroutines.
3. Since Perl array indices begin from zero, hence `$F[8]`, would really refer to the `ninth` element of the array `@F`.

Underlying assumptions are:

- The 8th field is a whole-field comparison and not partial. Meaning, the contents have to be exactly like you show here, not a character amiss.
- There are no fields which have commas in them, for that would split midfield and the field count goes for a toss.
- Not that it matters here, but just that you are aware that the line endings should ideally be Unix line endings (`LF = \n`). If they aren't, then you should convert them to it first.

Comment: Yea, may be assumptions you told are not fulfilled yet.

Comment: @DipitSethi What does your comment even mean? Which of the assumptions? There are a number of people here offering their help in solving your problem: I suggest you cooperate and post an input sample, detailed description of edge cases, and meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
First check What is there in the 8th column,

```
awk -F, '{print $8}' URT_Compare_20180715191103.csv
```

**Step 2:**
Then grep the desired pattern.

```
awk -F, '{print $8}' URT_Compare_20180715191103.csv | grep "WINDOWS2000-2"
```

**Step 3:**
If you get your desired result in step2, try the below code.

```
awk -F,  '$8 ~ "WINDOWS2000-2" ' URT_Compare_20180715191103.csv
```

Comment: Din't work. It gave empty output again.

Comment: @DipitSethi try the updated answer.

Comment: @DipitSethi if still getting empty output, share the file from **vim editor**

Comment: First step gives empty output, it is not able to get the column.

Comment: then, the problem might be with delimiter. can you share the result of `head -n5 URT_Compare_20180715191103.csv `